# psyonspotify app not loading the latest album

Tags: android, audio, spotify, libspotify

I added existing psyonspotify(https://github.com/spotify/psyonspotify) Android project into my Eclipse. I run the app and after I login using my premium Spotify account I see that the app just shows Loading the latest album and some icons. Nothing else is shown or played. Actually I want the app to play Spotify music so that I can look at music delivery callback and see what audio data is received. Can someone suggest me on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

libspotify for Android is deprecated and should not be used anymore. This project is also obsolete (yeah, we should probably update the README on it). Instead, try the new [Spotify SDK for Android](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/).

Comment: Thank you. But I did not see any functions that give pcm data of the audio in the new Spotify Android SDK Beta version. So I am really not understanding how to get raw pcm data of the audio via Android code.

Comment: You can override the Player class to get PCM data. It will be difficult but easier than working with libspotify.

Comment: Thank you. Can you let me know how could I acheive this. I see that most variables like maudiotrack and handler are private with no getter methods?

Comment: @DurgaMalleswari it will be more obvious once we release the source to the SDK, but basically you would need to override the methods which deliver PCM audio. You shouldn't need access to the AudioTrack or other objects. However I see that these methods are private and not protected, I will need to talk with my colleagues about exposing them.

Comment: Also it should be noted that the libspotify TOS prohibits modifying the PCM stream. So from a legal standpoint, we might be obligated to aid developers in accessing PCM data.